# How do you require only css files into a module with webpack

Tags: webpack

I'd like to use webpack with babel loader to take an es6 file and output an es5 file.

The es6 files have css requires that i'd like to be resolved.

They also import other files, which I want to not be resolved, as they will be resolved in a later build step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IgnorePlugin`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#ignoreplugin) and indicate which files to ignore using a regex. For example, the following will make webpack ignore all gif files:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.gif$/)
]
```